# ¿Por qué mi aplicación pesa mucho más de lo que debería?

Tags: c#

Pasa que mi aplicación pesaba 144 KB, y solo agregué 3 líneas y al publicarla el resultado pesa 67 MB, entonces limpié la solución y recompilé: sí se redujo pero a 13 MB, cuando debería pesar 144 KB.

sé que tiene que ver con librerías incluídas pero se supone que el sdk de .net las contiene y el programa debe llamarlas desde system32.

Comment: Y como estas compilando y/o publicando?

Comment: publicando como usted me enseñó, de hecho la primera vez que publiqué si me rseultó 144 KB, pero ahora lo más que logró reducir es a 10 MB

Comment: hola mi estimado Yussef, el problema era que el modo de implimentación,
el independiente guarda las librerías incluídas en el app mientras que dependiente de un marco de trabajo usa las librerías del sistema

Comment: Te recomiendo este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHIh5WoIvks